# What does "put stress on" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I looked up and figured out that "put stress on **something**" signifies that it emphasizes something.

 but I couldn't find what does "put stress on **someone**" means

> The next day,  I threw it in her face and told her,  "I'm not doing
>   your homework anymore. it **puts too much stress on me**, and it keeps me
>   from doing the things I love." And I never saw those girls again

This is what I read, and I don't think "it puts too much stress on me" means "it emphasized me" in this sentence.

Does it means "it stressed me out" or something?

Comment: How about "It *stresses* me out"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to put too much stress on a person (especially in this context) means to stress someone out. *To stress* literally means *to press down* on or *to put pressure or tension on*.   We can express figurative tension or pressure using *stress* as well.  If you think about it, emphasizing something is making it the focal point as if you were pressing into it.  If you are interested, the etymology of *stress* meaning *emphasize* is "laying pressure on something by relying on it." [etymology of stress](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stress)